# Is it possible to use the reference operator in conjunction with other operators?

Tags: java, lambda

Let's say we got this class:

```
public class MyClass {
    final int value = 0;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Is it somehow possible to take the output of the `getValue()` method and increment it, or do any math with it, but by **using the reference operator** and not a lambda?

What I am looking to achieve is something like this, but **with reference operators**:

```
Function<MyClass, Integer> getVal = x -> x.getValue() + 1;
```

If I write something like this, I will get an error:

```
Function<MyClass, Integer> getVal = MyClass::getValue + 1;
```

Comment: `= IntegerWrapper::getId + 1;` and in your opinion on which instance should `getId` be invoked if you are not passing any??

Comment: See but you are not using it. That is the issue!

Comment: You are passing "method reference" but you are not specifying the context in which that method should be used. Thats one issue. Second issue is that it would not be a valid statemen anyway. What is wrong with lamba?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: With` x -> x.getValue() + 1; ` you have clearly stated that `x` is an input, and you do someything witht that `x`, `x.getValue()` in this case. `x` is your context to refer to. When you try something `MyClass::getValue + 1;` what would be the instance of `MyClass` to invoke `getValue` on in your opition????? Moreover, eg `public int x(){return 2} + 2;` is by no means a valid statement, but yet you would like it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, that's not possible.

A method reference is an expression, which has a value. The type of the value is computed at compile-time, depending on the context in which it is used (this is called a *poly expression*). A method reference is always an instance of a *functional interface*.

In your case, `MyClass::getValue` returns some compatible interface, but the expression `MyClass::getValue + 1` causes the `+` operator to have to deal with that interface.

---

In [JLS § 15.13.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3), you can read about method references.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that is the problem with lamba expressions here but you can always wrap your expressions and use references to those wrappers

```
stream.map(this::doIt)

public int doIt(MyClass x){
   return x.getValue()+1;
}
```